Trying to obtain a specific hyperlink url inside the pages of a list of links in R
I'm trying to scrape CFB data from
https://stathead.com/football/playerseasonfinder.cgirequest=1&match=player_season_combined&order_by=name_display_csk&year_min=2008&year_max=2024&positions%5B%5D=qb&draft_status=drafted&draft_pick_type=overall
a paid website. I'm able to to login through R and obtain the primary links (list of players and their hyperlinks), but now I'm trying to navigate to each hyperlink and obtain the url of the "College Stats" hyperlink shown here on the resulting pages (example)
https://www.profootballreference.com/players/Y/YounBr01.htm__hstc=205977932.109bbba6a8a9f532790724faa5fd5151.1714787967133.1714797301883.1714801232656.3&__hssc=205977932.16.1714801232656&__hsfp=3211688760
     library(httr)
     library(rvest)
     library(dplyr)
    
        my_session \<- session("https://stathead.com/users/login.cgi")
    
        log_in_form \<- html_form(my_session)\[\[1\]\]
    
        fill_form \<- set_values(log_in_form,username = "XXXX",password = "XXXX")
    
        fill_form$fields\[\[4\]\]$name \<- "button"
    
        session_submit(my_session,fill_form)
    
        url \<- session_jump_to(my_session,"https://stathead.com/football/playerseason-finder.cgi?request=1&match=player_season_combined&order_by=name_display_csk&year_min=2008&year_max=2024&p. ositions\[\]=qb&draft_status=drafted&draft_pick_type=overall")
    
    tbl \<- html_nodes(url, 'table')av_table \<- html_table(tbl, fill = TRUE,) |\> pluck(1)av_table |\> as.data.frame()
    
    av_table \<- av_table |\> select(Player, DrftYr)
    
    pro_links \<- url |\> html_nodes("#stats a") |\> html_attr("href")
    
    av_table \<- av_table |\> mutate(URL = pro_links)
    
    pro_links \<- av_table$URL
    
    get_college_link \<- function(pro_link) {pro_page \<- read_html(pro_link)college_stats_link \<- pro_page |\> html_nodes("p:nth-child(7) a") |\> html_attr("href")}
    
    college_url_column \<- sapply(pro_links, FUN = get_college_link)
    
    av_table \<- av_table |\> mutate(College_Stats_URLs = college_url_column)
    `

i'm very new to this so apologies for the messiness. I've gotten various outputs upon minor tweaks. Right now if i print the college_url_column i get
https://www.profootballreference.com/players/Y/YounBr01.htm__hstc=205977932.109bbba6a8a9f532790724faa5fd5151.1714787967133.1714797301883.1714801232656.3&\__hssc=205977932.16.1714801232656&\__hsfp=3211688760
"https://www.sports-reference.com/cfb/players/bryce-young-1.html"
That 2nd link is what should show up, but for each player.

Might you please [edit] your post to format your your code as indicated in How do I format my code blocks??  You're more likely to attract an answer if people can clearly distinguish your code from your written text.  Thanks!
